# Notepad++: disable auto-complete in comments

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ for C coding.

The auto-complete functionality in NP++ seems really naive. No matter where I am in a file, it always tries to give me a list of auto-complete suggestions (most of which are just random words, rather than function or variable names).

It becomes really annoying when I'm trying to write a long multi-line comment, and I keep having to hit escape at the end of lines because the auto-complete pop-up wants to change what I'm typing.

Is there a way to disable auto-complete inside comments?

Alternatively,

Is there a way to disable keyboard interactions with auto-complete? The time it saves by filling in text for me is negligible compared to the time it saves me from having to go and confirm that I'm spelling function or variable names correctly. So, it would be just about as useful if it always made suggestions, but where the arrow keys and enter interacted with the text, rather than the pop-up.

Comment: You can tell it to only appear on ctrl+space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go `Settings` →`Preferences` → `Auto-Completion` and from this point you can set whether you have auto-completion on words, functions or both.

At this point, I don't believe there is a way to disable auto-completion within comments.

A workaround is to turn off auto-completion using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for your code, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for your comments.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that you could open the suggestions pop-up by pressing Ctrl+Space when auto-complete was disabled.

Comment: Building off this, it would be nice if Notepad++ let us disable auto-completion within certain file types, for example .txt files. That's another way of saying "for certain languages" if you consider txt a language like Perl (.pl) etc.